# Crack the caesar cipher using SML

Tags: sml, modulo

I'm supposed to crack the Caesar cipher. 
I have to declare a function `crack : int * int -> int` so that if `(k, c)` are of the type `int`, where `k` is the decrypted text and `c` the encrypted text, calling `crack(k, c)` will return the key (mod 10) `n`, which is needed to get `c` to `k`.
An example would be that calling `crack(20458790, 64892134)` would return 4.

If `c` isn't a correctly encoding of `k`, the function doesn't have to actually work.

I hope I'm being clear enough here. I understand the actual assignment here (I have k and c, I need n), but I don't know how to show it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what should happen when the second number isn't a caesar encoding of the first, so I'm going to assume it does not matter.

So in order to get, you just need to take any digit (most conveniently the last) from the first number and subtract that from the digit at the same position of the second number.

In other words, you can just do:  `(c mod 10 - k mod 10) mod 10`

Comment: I forgot to add that, sorry. If the second number (c) isn't a proper encoding of the first, the function doesn't actually have to work. I tried what you suggested, but for some reason it's returning 6 instead of 4 when I input the numbers from above. Any idea why it would do this? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I finally got it. I just had to say (c mod 10 - k mod 10) mod 10 instead. I'm not sure why, but it works.

Comment: @George: Oops, yes, I switched up the variable names. It works because it's simply subtracting the last digit of k from the last digit of c. So if you add that difference to the last digit of c, you get the last digit of k. And the same goes for every other digit because all digits have the same difference.